# Prove that $\exists l\in\mathbb R, f(x,y)\rightarrow l$ when $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, compactness

Let $f:\mathbb R^*\times\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R $,
$\forall \phi:\mathbb R^* \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $\phi(x)\rightarrow 0$ when $x$ goes to $0$. When $x$ goes to $0$ :

$$\exists l\in\mathbb R,f(x,\phi(x))\rightarrow l$$

Prove that $\exists l\in\mathbb R, f(x,y)\rightarrow l$ when $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$.

I prove chronologically those assertion :

1. $\forall (a_n,b_n)\in\mathbb R^* \times \mathbb R,(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow(0,0) \Rightarrow \exists \psi :\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N, \exists l\in \mathbb R, f(a_\psi(n),b_\psi(n))\rightarrow l$
2. $\exists A\in\mathbb R, \exists \delta > 0, \forall (x,y)\in B(0,\delta), |f(x,y)|<A $
3. $\forall (a_n,b_n)\in\mathbb R^* \times \mathbb R,(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow(0,0) \Rightarrow \exists l\in \mathbb R, f(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow l$

Quick explanation :

1. We can specifically choose parts of $a_n$ such that there is no repetitions. Then we can use $\phi$ and finally prove a limit exist
2. We can create a sequence which goes to infinity. But by 1), it is not possible. So contradiction.
3. We have a sequence in a compact and there is only one limit possible.

But I still have a problem because I would like to prove that :
$\exists l\in \mathbb R,\forall (a_n,b_n)\in\mathbb R^* \times \mathbb R,(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow(0,0) \Rightarrow f(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow l$

I don't know how to do next.

Comment: I do not understand your argument for 3.

Comment: Thank you for having accepted my answer. Still, can you please explain what was your argument for your point 3?

Comment: Well, we know that $\forall (a_n,b_n), f(a_n,b_n) \in K$ where $K$ is compact. So, if we proof only one limit possible (from all subsequences of $(a_n,b_n)$) then it must be going to this limit. But it doesn't work quite well because we need to prove the limit is the same for every other sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compacity is useless and you can proceed more directly:

- For any sequence $(a,b)$ of pairs $(a_n,b_n)\in\mathbb R^*\times\mathbb R$ converging to $(0,0)$ *and such that the $a_n$'s are distinct*, $(f(a_n,b_n))$ has a limit $\ell_{(a,b)}\in\mathbb R$ (for this, construct some appropriate $\phi$).
- For any two *such* sequences $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, $\ell_{(a,b)}=\ell_{(c,d)}$ (for this, choose a third *such* sequence $(e,f)$ such that $(e_{2n},f_{2n})$ is a subsequence of $(a,b)$ and $(e_{2n+1},f_{2n+1})$ is a subsequence of $(c,d)$).
- Let $\ell$ be the common value of all these $\ell_{(a,b)}$, then $\lim_{(0,0)}f=\ell$ (else there would exist some $\varepsilon>0$ and some  $(a_n,b_n)\in\mathbb R^*\times\mathbb R$ converging to $(0,0)$ and such that $|f(a_n,b_n)-\ell|\ge\varepsilon$, and the $a_n$'s could be chosen distinct, whence a contradiction).

Answer (score 1):

Ooh, that's a fun one.

Consider two sequences $(a_n,b_n)$ and $(a_n',b_n')$ that go to zero, their image by $f$ converges to $l$ and $l'$ respectively.

Create a third sequence $(\hat a_n,\hat b_n)$ by alternating between the two. If you look at $f(\hat a_n,\hat b_n)$, its odd subsequence goes to $l$, and its even susbequence goes to $l'$. But by your (3), it must converge. So $l=l'$.